# Moving directories from one server to the other

Tags: linux, scp

I am able to move files using the commands suggested in

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh

but I wanted to know how to alter the command so that I can move a whole directory rather than a file.

For more context, I want to alter

```
scp /path/to/file username@a:/path/to/destination
```

to something like

`scp /path/to/DIRECTORY username@a:/path/to/destination`

Comment: Do I just need to add `-r` after `scp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only add the `-r` flag to copy recursively (as with many other Linux/Unix commands e.g. cp, rm, grep, etc...).

`scp -r /path/to/DIRECTORY user@host:/path/to/destination`